# ¿Como puedo insertar las datos que contiene un JLabel a una BD?

Tags: java

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto, por el momento estoy en el registro de colaboradores de una empresa, y me funciona perfecto al hacer los registros.

En mi BD, implementé una tabla en la que llevo el control de las altas de manera oculta en el botón de registro; quien hace los movimientos, el id (autoincrement), el nombre de quien lo hace, la fecha y la hora en que fue hecho el registro; para ello, la información se muestra en los `JLabel` correspondientes, lo hice de dos manera y no me hace el registro.

La primera es: asignando el contenido de los `JLabel` a las variables. (`JOptionPane` solo son para saber si las variables extrajeron correctamente los datos).

```
    private void control_registros(){
    String dat = lblfecha.getText();
    String hour = lblhora.getText();
    String usu = lblusuario.getText();
    String sql = "INSERT INTO control_altas VALUES ("
                + "'"+0+"',"
                + "'"+usu+"'"
                + "'"+dat+"'"
                + "'"+hour+"')";
    try {
        stm = conn.createStatement();
        stm.executeUpdate(sql);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "El usuario "+usu+" con fecha "+dat+" se han registrado con éxito a las "+hour);
    } catch (SQLException | HeadlessException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "El usuario "+usu+" con fecha "+dat+" no se pudieron registrar a las "+hour);
    }
}
```

Y la segunda es:

```
    private void control_registros(){
    String sql = "INSERT INTO control_altas VALUES ("
                + "'"+0+"',"
                + "'"+lblusuario.getText()+"'"
                + "'"+lblfecha.getText()+"'"
                + "'"+lblhora.getText()+"')";
    try {
        stm = conn.createStatement();
        stm.executeUpdate(sql);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "El usuario "+usu+" con fecha "+dat+" se han registrado con éxito a las "+hour);
    } catch (SQLException | HeadlessException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "El usuario "+usu+" con fecha "+dat+" no se pudieron registrar a las "+hour);
    }
}
```

Todos los registros que se hacen en el proyecto se ejecutan a la perfección, siempre y cuando el contenido se extraiga de los `JTextField` o `JComboBox` que tengo en cada uno de los `JFrames`.

Comment: La fecha de los JLebels debe estar formateada con este formato `yyyy-MM-dd`, la hora con este `HH:mm:ss`. Solo los campos de fecha u hora deben llevar comillas simples ('). Por último, qué es ese `0` en el primer parámetro?

Comment: `0` estoy asignando el `autoincrement`, ¿en la  BD afecta que la fecha y la hora sean de tipo `varchar`?

Comment: El `autoincrement` no se asigna, simplemente no se pasa ningún valor a ese parámetro, o sea solo le pasas `usu`,`dat`,`hour`, además deben ir separados por coma(,). Y sí, afecta en el sentido que no vas a poder operar con esos valores de fecha y/u hora, por ejemplo sumar o restar días, etc.

Comment: Gracias por la observación, ya estaba algo saturado, y jamás me percaté de ello, las comas (,). Los tipos de dato se corrigieron el la BD y solucionado. Nuevamente gracias.